# Bootable USB Stick to install Ubuntu22.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my new Thinkpad Laptop, which does not have any OS at the moment. I have always done this from DVD, but apparently 22.04 is too big for a DVD.
I want to buy a USB stick, download Ubuntu 22, using my old Laptop, on which there is Ub. 20.04, then boot 22.04 on the new thinkpad.
The question is ***How many GB must the USB have? 128? 256? or what?***
Thank you!
Monica

Comment: Here is [the link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) to the tutorial.

Comment: You can answer this for yourself by simply looking at the size of the downloaded .iso file.

Comment: The following link and links from it will help you create a bootable USB drive to install current Ubuntu versions. You need at least 8 GB, but I suggest that you get a USB3 drive with 16 GB or more. Link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: 8GB is plenty, but if you’re going to install and then use the usb for other things (ie wipe the iso after installation), you may as well get one big enough for eg backup / file transfers etc. 128-256 GB is (in my view) the sweet spot where you get best value for money, ie lowest cost per GB from a reputable brand.

Comment: Thank you. I will take the 128 GB

Comment: You should not edit questions to change their meaning after an answer is posted. You should have accepted the answer to this, then posted a new question. Why did you edit this into a duplicate of the new question? Now this one is botched, and the other one will be closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: Once the other one is closed, you should revert your edit to this and accept the answer. Then edit the other one for clarity and perhaps it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

8 GB Is enough for single installation.

With 128 or more you can have multiple bootable .iso files on it using https://www.ventoy.net/

Comment: Thank you. That perfectly answers my question, Monica